# Web API post parameter is always null

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api2

I am always getting **model** as null when trying to call action using Fiddler or Postman rest client agents.This issue is only coming on IIS 8.0 server hosted web application and on my local machine and website using asp.net development server on same server is giving value in model.I think it is some kind of missing/blocked settings of IIS which is doing this.Please help me out to resolve this issue as I have already spent 1 day on this.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. Give what method you're calling, parameters, etc.

Comment: Adding more information to above issue when I check in chrome the Request Payload contains the value I am sending in JSON data but in server it is always changing to null. It is only happening on IIS hosted applications.

Comment: Any help on above issue.I am using window azure machine running IIS 8.0